# CSS make div take up the rest of space

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this setup:

```
 <div class="parent">
   <div class="moverBoy"></div>
   <div class="smartBoy"></div>
 </div>
```

The *parent* is a for-ever-fixed element at say 100x20.

*moverBoy* and *smartBoy* always have 20 height and are **inline-block** and **vertical-align: top** so they are next to each other with no whitespaces or text anywhere.

*moverBoy*'s width changes either with JS or CSS animations. What I need to do is have smartBoy change his width to always take up the rest of the width so that the parent is always filled.

Comment: css please! Please post your css code.

Comment: Checkout css Flex! it does exactly what you are wanting to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get exactly what you are looking for by floating `.moverBoy` and modifying the `overflow` of `.smartBoy` (Works all the way back to IE6 or so!):

```js
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementsByClassName('moverBoy')[0].style.width = '100px';
}
```

```css
body{ margin:0 }
.moverBoy{
    float: left;
    background:#F00;
    width:300px;
    transition: width 2s;
}
.smartBoy{
    overflow: hidden;
    background:#0F0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div class="moverBoy">&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="smartBoy">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could have your snippet behave like a table:

```js
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementsByClassName('moverBoy')[0].style.width = '100px';
}
```

```css
body{ margin: 0; }
.parent{
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
}
.moverBoy{
    display: table-cell;
    background:#F00;
    width:300px;
    transition: width 2s;
}
.smartBoy{
    display: table-cell;
    background:#0F0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div class="moverBoy">&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="smartBoy">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Either way, you can change the width of the parent element or `.moverBoy` and `.smartBoy` will adjust accordingly.

Comment: Awesome! I guess I could have come up with the first snippet if I didn't have a deadline's gun touching my forehead. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of CSS3 `flex`. In this snippet below, hover on any of the `xBoys` and their width will change to `75%` and the other will fill the available space. Works only in modern browsers, though.

You have to just apply your width to the `.moverBoy` through `flex-basis` property. So, `flex: 1 1 75%` will change its width to `75%` and adjusting `.smartBoy` accordingly. Other properties are auto `grow` and `shrink` with `1` being yes.

**Snippet**:

```css
.parent {
    width: 100px; height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: columns;
}
.parent > div {
    flex: 1 1 0%;
    transition: all 500ms;
}
.parent > div:hover {
    flex: 1 1 75%;
}
.moverBoy { background-color: #f00; }
.smartBoy { background-color: #00f; }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div class="moverBoy"></div>
   <div class="smartBoy"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, because mover and smart are on a separate line, they automatically have whitespace inbetween. You can get around this by making them the same line, or adding comments like so:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="moverBoy"></div><!--
   --><div class="smartBoy"></div>
</div>
```

For the css, you could simply use Calc:

```
.moverBoy {
    width:20px;
}
.smartBoy {
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

Here is a little example of it working: http://jsfiddle.net/083pnubk/

Comment: I know they would but they are constructed with JS. That's why I mentioned there is no whitespace. Your solution suggests that smartboy needs to change with JS everytime. I want a CSS solution! Plus calc is evil compatibility wise.

Comment: also: _"moverBoy's width changes either with JS or CSS animations"_ implies that you are looking for JS solution too.